# Adding speed to Quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rotating an object with the position of my VR Hand. The issue is that the object rotates quite slowly with respect to the hand movement. Is it possible to add speed to the Quaternion so that it rotates faster and I could control the speed?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateModel : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool triggerClicked = false;
    public Transform rightHand;
    private Quaternion initialObjectRotation;
    private Quaternion initialControllerRotation;
    private bool set = false;

    void Update () {
        if (triggerClicked) {
            if (set == false) {
                initialObjectRotation = transform.rotation;
                initialControllerRotation = rightHand.rotation;
                set = true;
            }
            Quaternion relativeRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(rightHand.rotation) * initialControllerRotation;
            transform.rotation = rightHand.rotation * relativeRotation;
        } else {
            set = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped`. I'm not quite sure about your code. But you will be able to use it in a way like this:

```
...
var appliedRotation = ...
var scaledAppliedRotation = Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped(Quaternion.identity, appliedRotation, rotateSpeed);
...
```

a `rotateSpeed` of `0` means that we don't apply any rotation (cause it will be the Identity Quaternion). `1` means the `appliedRotation` is applied 1:1. And any value greater or lower will change the rotated amount accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your response but i am not sure how to do this in my code? what should I change?